# Clear Parse Push Notification Dashboard List

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using `Parse` to send push notifications to my app. after sending some tests I wanna clear the push notifications dashboard list but I can't find any remove option!! How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature currently exists for parse.com You can refer below links for more info:

https://parse.com/questions/remove-push-notification-history-entries-from-web-console

https://parse.com/questions/delete-push-notifications-history

Comment: Yes I know but still this feature is yet to come & for more details you can discuss this with support team of parse.com